# Return values from one dictionary by comparing keys from another dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have two dictionaries and I want to get the values of the first dictionary for the keys of the second. Both the dictionaries have the same keys but in different order.
For example:

```
dict1={'a':1,'b':1,'c':0,'d':0,'e':1,'f':0,'g':1}
```

This is the first dictionary. And the second dictionary is:

```
dict2={'c':3,'b':2,'a':1,'d':1,'e':0,'g':0,'f':0}
```

I want to get the values corresponding to the first dictionary but in the order of keys of the second dictionary.
So the output should be like this:

```
dict3={'c':0,'b':1,'a':1,'d':0,'e':1,'g':1,'f':0}
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Why would you want to sort a dict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have you have Python 3.7+ you can use this:

```
dict1={'a':1,'b':1,'c':0,'d':0,'e':1,'f':0,'g':1}
dict2={'c':3,'b':2,'a':1,'d':1,'e':0,'g':0,'f':0}

dict3 = {k: dict1[k] for k in dict2.keys()}
print(dict3)

> {'c': 0, 'b': 1, 'a': 1, 'd': 0, 'e': 1, 'g': 1, 'f': 0}
```

[What’s New In Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html)

> the insertion-order preservation nature of dict objects has been declared to be an official part of the Python language spec.

Comment: Thanks. This works perfectly. I was looking for this.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you meant?

```
dict3 = {key:dict1[key] for key in dict2.keys()}
```

Tried on python 3.9.

Comment: Thanks. Yes this is exactly what I meant.